# I have not been able to log in to Stack Overflow for the past two days

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

Is there something wrong with the login servers for Stack Overflow? I am able to log in to the other sites in the network fine. But on SO, the page keeps saying welcome back...redirecting...welcome to qa...redirecting...welcome to qa...&c.

Hopefully this is the right place to post this question.

I really do not want to lose my "you have accessed this page every day for 10 years" badge.

Comment: Haha, I'm working towards the fanatic badge as well.  It would suck to lose it because of technical difficulties.

Comment: Also, this is the right place to post the question.

Comment: 10 years... **wow** !!

Comment: I only have 9 years and 10 months more to go! Seriously though the login..redirect..login..redirect..login...n is getting kind of frustrating.

Comment: I emailed the stackoverflow team and will post their response when I get it.

Answer (score 1):

After hearing from the team at stackoverflow.com that my account looked fine and they didn't know what was wrong with it. I started changing settings, added stackoverflow.com to my trusted sites, always allowed cookies, found a damaged adobe object and removed it, manually removed all of my cookies again, reinstalled IE 8 and rebooted my computer. One of those things solved my problem, I then proceeded to email the team at stackoverflow and begged them ever so humbly to please not let my consecutive days reset. It took me 3 hours to accomplish all of those tasks and I am the balder for it.

This is still not an answer because I have no idea what the true cause of the problem was. The fly in the ointment is that I was still able to login to meta, the cooking site and the gaming site with no problems, just not stackoverflow. Along with every other website in the known universe where I have an account to login to.

I did check my event logs just to be thorough and there was nothing of note there.

Comment: generally it's more productive to handle per-user-specific things through email.